# Use Angular cli with existing project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have an existing project and I want to use the angular cli generator, so After install and create the following `.angular-cli` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src/mc2/components",
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": { }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I generate a new component it created inside:

```
/src/mc2/components/app/todos/...
```

How can I remove the app folder, what I really need is:

```
/src/mc2/components/todos/...
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all you have to follow the CLI project structure, so just run `ng new my-app` and make sure that you have a matching structure in your project, once it is done change your `"root": "src/mc2/components"` to `"root": "src"` in `.angular-cli.json`

If you are in the root of your project folder the rule is

- `ng g c something` - create `something` component in `src/app/something`
- `ng g c /components/something` - create `something` component in `src/app/components/something`

Also you can use `--flat` flag to create a component without a dedicated folder
You can add `--dry-run` just to see what the command is gonna do

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, seems that i mislead you. Because of the angular-cli style guide the `ng g component something` always places your generated component inside an app folder. Didn't find a way to change this except manually doing so. But when you generate a new file it just generates a new app folder. So for now i dont think they have made a way to do this yet.

Comment: I don't understand, the prefix as a meaning in the structure?